# How to create an array of objects dynamically in javascript for a pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am working on creating dynamic values for a pie chart which is a graph from chart.js
I have created a variable which contains multiple object values which needs to be passed in the array for pie graph. 
If I pass the variable nothing shows up but if I pass the same static values to the variable the pie chart starts working.
I searched for various methods but could not make it work with my code. 
My code looks like this:

```
  /*PIE Chart*/
    var elements = [];
    var counter;
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax-request.php',
  data: {},
  success: function(response){
    //here data is means the out put from the php file it is not           
     $('#StudentID').val()
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(elements); 
        var pieData;
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            counter = jsonData[i];
            var sale = roundFloat(counter.sales,2);
            elements+= '{value:'+sale+',color: "#FDB45C",highlight: "#FFC870",label:"'+counter.sku+'"},';

        }
        var pieData = [elements];

    var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chartjs").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
   } 
   });
```

Comment: Do you have an error when using the variable?

Comment: Hint: `elements` is a string hence pieData is an array of one element i.e the string value of elements. I guess the `Pie` function is supposed to take an array of objects.

Comment: I get this value in console for 'elements' : {value:9982154.22,color: "#FDB45C",highlight: "#FFC870",label:"GL2010B"},{value:1473462.15,color: "#FDB45C",highlight: "#FFC870",label:"PL009"},{value:1009087.15,color: "#FDB45C",highlight: "#FFC870",label:"PL006"}, which comes dynamic from ajax request. When I pass this complete response copied from console the Pie chart works. But it doest work when I pass the variable 'elements'.

Comment: I don't get any error if I use this variable.

Comment: How can I create a key value pair as an object like this `color: "#FFC870"
highlight: "#FFC871"
label: "Some Name"
value: 50`
Currently I am getting the output 0 as key and the complete string as its value which is incorrect. `0: "{value:217419.2,color: "#be4bc7",highlight: "#FFC870",label:"Some name"},"`    Any Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes to your code to make this work.

`pieData` should be an array of objects. So instead of appending a string, you need to [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the object into the array. Once you do that that `elements` is an array of objects and you can directly assign it to `pieData`

Below is the changed code block

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    counter = jsonData[i];
    var sale = roundFloat(counter.sales, 2);
    elements.push({
        value: sale,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: counter.sku
    })
}
var pieData = elements;
```